# Split string in two rows in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

From this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/01/01 | AAA, BBB |
| 2021/01/02 | CCC, DDD |

To this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/01/01 | AAA |
| 2021/01/01 | BBB |
| 2021/01/02 | CCC |
| 2021/01/02 | DDD |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataStudio doesn't offer a solution for this kind of data manipulation.

However, this can be easily done with BigQuery or most modern databases.

```sql
WITH table AS (
    SELECT '2021/01/01' date, 'AAA, BBB' values
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021/01/02' date, 'CCC, DDD' values
)
SELECT
    table.date
    , value
FROM
    table
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(table.values,', ')) value
```

**Result**:

[image: table]